# CSS3 left animation only working in Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations

I have this animation (assume I've used appropriate vendor prefixes):

```
@keyframes animIn {
    10% {
        left: 10%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
    90% {
        left: 90%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Which works fine in Chrome, but in IE and Firefox the left property doesn't animate. In IE they animated element stays to the left (looks like `left: 0`) and in Firefox the animated element is centered (probably due to a `text-align: center`). The animated element has `position: absolute`, and it fades in and out like it's supposed to in all the major browsers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding a `0%{}` and a `100%{}` I have seen IE not work without these two.

Comment: This is your issue right? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/Lmh3nt6p/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin-left` instead of `left` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lmh3nt6p/4/

```
@keyframes animIn {  

    10% {
        margin-left: 10%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
    90% {
        margin-left: 90%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```